# How can I cancel the tension force in this problem?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, electrostatics, electric-fields, coulombs-law

[image]

Hello, everybody. I am a high school student, and I need your help to solve this problem. Suppose that  both charges in blue has $Q = 1,2\times 10^{-6}$ C, and that the mass of each sphere is $ m = 3\times 10^{-4}$ kg. The diagram represents an equilibrium system. If we put a charge in the point $O$ (point of suspension), what would be its value in order to cancel the tension forces applied on the strings.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'cancel' the tension?

Comment: Well, actually, this is part of my question. The question actually uses the term "null". "Cancel" was my interpretation.

Comment: I don't fully understand the question here. Tension forces are reaction forces that can adjust to whatever they need to, in order to balance it out (unless they break). You could put any charge (with opposite sign) at $O$ (as long as the string won't break), and the string tension forces would adjust to balance out this new load.

Comment: If I understood your point of view, we have the same ideas about the system. What I just don´t get is the idea of making "null" the tension force. As far as I can tell, you can have a null work, considering equal vectors acting in opposite directions. But how does the tension dissapears  with a negative charge, considering the situation created by the author of the problem?

Comment: I think my interpretation is: what amount of charge do you need to place at O such that if you cut the strings the blue charges remain stationary.

Comment: So to solve it, you need to calculate the tension in the string, set that equal to the electrostatic force and then use Coulomb's law to find the charge. Remember to think about the sign of the charge!

Comment: Thank you so much, jobal6. Honestly, your few words were the essencial on my knowledge process. Again, thank you very much. I have just found the same answer as the book shows.